# Rails 3 Migration screw ups

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I recently added `Devise` and `CanCan` to my `Rails 3.2.3` app and need to run `rake db:migrate` in order to get them working properly. I have a migration file for links that I created already and it is somehow conflicting with when I run `rake db:migrate`

```
==  CreateLinks: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:links)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "links" already exists: CREATE TABLE "links" ("id"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "url" varchar(255), "description" var
char(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "points" integer, "updated_at" dateti
me NOT NULL)
```

I tried running `rake db:migrate:reset` but this seems to do nothing to help my situation. I still cant run a db migration for my new gems. How can I get around this? Can I omit the links migration somehow?

Comment: you try to create a table that already exists! delete your table "links" or use "rake db:rollback" if that was your last migration and then run again "rake db:migrate".

Comment: tried db:rollback but that didnt still gave me the same issue. how can i delete the table 'links' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sDid you create the links table manually before running the migration? Somehow you seem to have gotten your migrations out of sync with your database.

If you are not concerned about any of the data in the database, you can do a `rake db:drop` first, then do the `rake db:migrate`. This blows away all the tables in the database and run all the migrations again from the beginning.

If you do need to maintain the existing database tables, then you could wrap the `create_table :links` statement with an `unless table_exists? :links` statement.

Comment: rake db:drop lol..... somehow my migrations got out of sync and I didnt know the correct commands other than rake db:migrate and rake db:reset .... thanks again!

Comment: Here's one to remember: rake -T  Displays a description of available rake options.